# Galaxy Note 2 screen problems

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I'm experiencing a spot of trouble with my N7105 Samsung Galaxy Note 2 device. It boots up just fine, the screen works absolutely flawlessly for a few minutes, but then the problems start to appear. The screen progressively develops black bars, it stops refreshing in places, beginning from the bottom of the screen and moving upwards, and before too long the entire screen is covered in random noise.

Now, since this problem only manifests after the device has been turned on for some time, it makes sense to me if it were an overheating problem. I've pulled the phone apart and have thoroughly cleaned the cables and connectors to the motherboard with ethanol, but it doesn't seem to have improved the situation much.

If anyone has any kind of experience with this kind of problem, please report back.

Comment: Just because it happens when your phone has been active for a while doesn't necessarily mean it has to be an overheating problem, is your phone running a custom ROM?

Comment: Nope, and one of the first things I did was to reset the phone to factory default.

Comment: It sounds like a defective screen to me, are the cables intact for the screen and the digitizer?

Comment: As far as I can see, the cables and connections are swell, but I have no idea what the story is after they disappear down into the innards of the phone, since you need to break out a heat gun and a razorblade to get at the actual back of the screen.